# can I use different scrapy downloader for different rules?

Tags: python, scrapy

here is my situation:
I want to crawl different page use different down-loader:
as we can use different url-libs to load different webpages, e.g. urllib2/httplib. so I want to create two more download functions in  downloader middleware file.

```
def downloader1():
    use urllib2 to open url-type1

def downloader2():
    use scrapy default downloader to open url-type2
```

I just think about if there is any way like url parse rules as below? for different url, we can call back different downloader1 or downloader2 to download page.

Another question, Can I use different downloader for different spiders in the same project?